# How do I run FSI from Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: f#, visual-studio-2017

The help [at Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/tutorials/fsharp-interactive/) explains

"To run F# Interactive through Visual Studio, you can click the appropriate toolbar button labeled F# Interactive, or use the keys Ctrl+Alt+F. Doing this will open the interactive window, a tool window running an F# Interactive session. You can also select some code that you want to run in the interactive window and hit the key combination ALT+ENTER. F# Interactive starts in a tool window labeled F# Interactive. When you use this key combination, make sure that the editor window has the focus."

I am using VS2017 professional.
I have F# language support checked in the .Net desktop development work load but I cant find the F# Interactive button.

What toolbar should I be looking in for it>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use the menu bar: `View > Other Windows > F# Interactive`.

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio has a handy quick launch bar at the top that you can use to search. F# Interactive is here:

[image]

To be honest, the "toolbar" you are looking for is actually [VsCode with Ionide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/get-started/get-started-vscode). :D

Comment: Thanks for the VS Code with Ionide tip